Getting a better waffle split (stroopwafels)
I'm currently trying to make stroopwafels on an electric stroopwafel maker, and I've had a decent amount of success; my waffles come out brown on both sides, and after cutting them into a circle with a cookie cutter to remove the edges I can split them in half with a knife and a small amount of elbow grease to spread on the filling.
However, in a short video posted by the de facto Dutch stroopwafel company on how they make stroopwafels, the waffle appears to be practically splitting itself in half directly off the waffle iron - seemingly no edge removal required.
As holding down multiple hot waffles to split apart does a number to one's hands, I'd love to get my waffles to behave like this. Could this behavior just be due to a combination of a hot waffle iron and and an undercooked middle, in which case I would just need to play around with my settings, or could something like the moisture or fat content be playing a role here?
I've linked the recipe I've been using for the curious, but most available recipes don't deviate much from this preportionally, leading me to believe it's a settings issue. However, I don't have much experience with waffles, so I thought I'd ask here before I go forking out for more supplies to experiment with.

I do guess the middle needs to be uncooked, see this: https://youtu.be/Lb18_PYQ_Xo?t=1170 where they talk about it being uncooked in the middle, and being unable to cut it if it were cooked. I'd play around with settings on the iron or perhaps make slightly thicker waffles.

In the short video they say "35 seconds" but I'd call that on the long side.

Seeing stroopwafel makers on the markets in the Netherlands, most will use a cookie cutter.

I am from Gouda, home of the Stroopwafel, and I have NEVER seen them split like they do in this video. I am suspecting this is edited to make it look more simple than it is. It even looks like it is pre-cut.

From the videos in the question and in the comments (and from watching stroopwafel being made in the market / shops) it seems the outside needs to cook quickly before the center dries out completely, so it's still pliable.
If you're following the same recipe and yours doesn't split easily I'd increase the temperature of the iron, so the outside crust forms quicker.
You can see in this video that they had to flip the stropwafel because one side was darker than the other. You might need to do that in order to avoid overcooking the center before the outside is done.
If you can't increase the temperature anymore I'd try to make the wafel a little bit thicker, so you would be able to toast the outside properly keeping the center soft.
